# How can I get the timer started from the user input NOT the just constant value and keep my session storage still working?

Tags: javascript, timer, session-storage

I made a timer going even after reloading the page using javascript's session storage.
BUT regarding the timer at the first place, I want to get it started from getting USER INPUT.

Instead of specific number of time like 300(what I did so far below), I want to get a value from the user. Like, when the user clicked on a button on the page a pop up shows up asking the user how much time you want to put for the timer and the user put the value whatever he/she wants and the timer gets started upon that.

```
var userTime1 = 300;

var time = sessionStorage.getItem('timer_time');
var min = sessionStorage.getItem('timer_min');
var sec = sessionStorage.getItem('timer_sec');

if (!time){
    time = userTime1;
    min = parseInt(time/60);
    sec = time%60;
}

var interval = setInterval(function () {
  time--;
  min = parseInt(time/60);
  sec = time%60;

  sessionStorage.setItem('timer_time', time);
  sessionStorage.setItem('timer_min', min);
  sessionStorage.setItem('timer_sec', sec);

  document.getElementById("timeLeft1").innerHTML = min + "min" + sec + "sec";
};

  if (time == 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    sessionStorage.removeItem('timer_time');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('timer_min');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('timer_sec');
    sessionStorage.clear();

    alert("Timer Expired!");
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You can use [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt). `var userTime1 = prompt('How long is the timer?');`.

Comment: but when I did that, the timer was reset (the field data was gone) after the page reloaded. it's no use that I used the session storage then:(